# Django: Problems setting up django-allauth URLs

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm trying to customize a few things of allauth and ran into the following problem. I got my own account app, which is supposed to handle all the customization I do to allauth amongst other account related stuff.

Which means I want to include the allauth urls into the urls.py located in my account app, not in the project level urls.py. However when I try it with the code below I run into the following error:

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'account_login' not found. 'account_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    ...
    path('account/', include('apps.account.urls')),    # This does not work
    # path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),       # This works
   ...
)
```

**apps/account/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include('allauth.urls')),    #This is where I want to include the allauth urls
    ...
)
```

Going one step further: Can I customize the allauth urls in some way? When I try something like the following I get the same error as above:

**apps/account/urls.py**

```
from allauth.account import views as allauth_view


urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("login_custom/", allauth_view.login, name="account_login"),
    ...
)
```

EDIT: The last part with the custom url for logins actually works, but only if I include all of the allauth urls in my project level urls.py as well.

EDIT 2: After installing django-extensions and running `manage.py show_urls` to get a list of all urls in my project I noticed this might be a namespace problem.

for the nested include `path('account/', include('apps.account.urls')),` it shows me:

```
...
/de/account/social/signup/ allauth.socialaccount.views.SignupView account:socialaccount_signup
...
```

for including it in the project level urls.py `path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),` it shows me:

```
...
/de/account/social/signup/ allauth.socialaccount.views.SignupView socialaccount_signup
...
```

Do you guys think this might be the problem?

Since you can call include() with a namespace parameter this should not be a problem. However after checking the urls.py of the allauth package there is no `app_name`, which means I cannot set a namespace. Is there a way to remove the `account` namespace from the first example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you remember to add \_\_init\_\_.py inside apps directory?

Comment: Yes, i got init.py. Other urls from apps/account/urls.py also work, just the `include('allauth.urls')`part is giving me trouble.

Comment: Remove the login url and try

Comment: I alway left this commented out in my tries. Please check my 2nd edit.

Comment: I solved it: removing app_name from my account app also removed the namespace and now it works.